# jQuery MegaMenu hover setTime out/hoverIntent problem

Tags: jquery, settimeout, hoverintent

I am trying to put a jQ MegaMenu on a my web page.
I used Geek Tantra's plugin (http://www.geektantra.com/2009/09/jquery-mega-menu/) and did some minor changes from there.

Problems - the menu is in the middle of the screen - so I need to users to be able to pass the mouse thru the nav menu wihtout activating the menus.

I tried to use jq hoverIntent plug-in - but this broke the ability to use the megamenu window that opens it. Now it closes too soon and the menus don't really behave properly.
Sample of this here...http://jdshipengrover.com/megamenutest/megamenu-intent.html

I also tried the setTimeout jq function - but now the menu opens up whenever the trigger is pass over - it doesn't know to not open the menu...
Example here...http://jdshipengrover.com/megamenutest/megamenu-timeout.html.

I'm so close to having what I need - I just don't know how to get there.
Any help would be appreciated.

If you need me to post the actual js here - let me know.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please post some sample code relating to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well - no response on this, but that's OK.
I went back and rebuilt it from scratch using the hoverIntent JQ addon and seem to be behaving properly across browser.

I have no idea how I fixed it, but I did.

Sometimes you just have to start over.